# How to prove the following function is strictly convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given that $T: X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator between Hilbert spaces. Now how to prove that $$||Tx-y||^2+ \alpha ||x||^2$$  is a strictly convex functional where $\alpha > 0$ is a constant and $x \in C$ which is convex and closed subset of $X$.

I know that a function is strictly convex if for $a \neq b$ $$f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b) < \lambda f(a)+ (1-\lambda) f(b)$$

Comment: prove it on $x \mapsto \|Tx\|^2$ and you're done

Comment: The convexity of $\| x \|$ is easily derived from the triangle inequality.  You can then show that the norm of a linear transformation $Tx-y$ is convex.  Next, you show that the square of a norm is convex.  Finally, the sum of two convex functions is convex.  For the strict convexity, use properties of the norm of show that $\| x \|^{2}$ is strictly convex.